# Is it necessary to network enable both the parent and child theme for multisite installations?

Tags: multisite, themes, child-theme, parent-theme

for multisite networks, is it necessary for me to network enable both the parent and child theme if I'm only using the child theme in my sites?

Does it cause my site to slow down if I have more themes network-enabled?

When a parent theme gets updated, do I have to perform any action on the child theme?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to the party, came across this question looking for the same answer myself - to answer your first question, I've done a brief test locally and it seems that the parent theme *can* be network disabled. I have three sites running, with three child themes network enabled where the parent theme is not and they're all still standing.